# irb and rails console show different results for [].blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

why irb and rails console show different results for [].blank?

**Here is my irb check:**

```
$ irb
2.1.0 :001 > a = []
 => [] 
2.1.0 :002 > a.blank?
NoMethodError: undefined method `blank?' for []:Array
    from (irb):2
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

**Here is my console check:**

```
$ rails c -e local
Loading local environment (Rails 4.1.5)
2.1.0 :001 > a = []
 => [] 
2.1.0 :002 > a.blank?
 => true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Requiring ActiveSupport Extensions

The [Object#blank?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) method is part of Rails' [ActiveSupport Core Extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html). Rails includes ActiveSupport by default. However, these extensions can also be installed independently of Rails [as a gem](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport).

You can include portions of ActiveSupport in other applications or in your interactive REPL sessions by requiring the parts of ActiveSupport that you need. For example, to mix in support for the #blank? method:

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank'

[].blank?
# => true
```

Answer (score 6):

the `blank?` method is added by rails (doesn't belong to the standard ruby language)
From the rails docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb, line 15
def blank?
  respond_to?(:empty?) ? !!empty? : !self
end
```